# Magento DHL This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using DHL shipping methods in Magento. I have all the credentials Correct in Admin. After That Showing error in checkout "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us."

and in DHL log not showing error but showing this DEBUG message:

2016-07-29T04:56:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => Zero shipping charge for 'Domestic express'
    [1] => Zero shipping charge for 'Express easy'
    [__pid] => 17282
)

What Should I do. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check your settings once again. If the issue still there try contacting DHL.

Note: DHL test mode will have the problem of not giving rates. If you are using it in Test mode. Please try in live mode.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem. Please upvote it Surender Singh.

Comment: I can't dear bcz my reputation is too cheap